# Many-to-Many Database design with Django

Tags: python, django, database, database-design

Oftentimes a single drug can have lots of "nick names" which gets confusing. So, I'm trying to build a small Django app to help me with the issue.

What it should do is either refer the drugs acutal name (non_proprietary_name) to its "nick name" (proprietary_name) or vice versa.

For instance, "Aspirin" and "ASS" are the proprietary_name for "acetylsalicylic acid".

To complicate it a bit further I've decided to add a small Wiki page and categories (also, a drug can fall into many different categories).

Sadly, I'm not very familiar with database design, so that's where I need a bit of help.

What I've got so far:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Proprietary_name(models.Model):
    proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True) #nick name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.proprietary_name

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Mediwiki(models.Model):
    proprietary_name = models.ManyToManyField(Proprietary_name)
    non_proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True) # actual name
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    wiki_page = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.non_proprietary_name

~
```

So, if I've got the proprietary_name I can relate to the non_proprietary_name:

```
>>> Mediwiki.objects.get(proprietary_name__proprietary_name='Aspirin')
<Mediwiki: acetylsalicylic acid>
```

However, I'm having trouble getting all the non_proprietary_names when I enter the proprietary one. Is this an issue with my Database or am I missing something else?

EDIT:

New models.py based on the comments:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Mediwiki(models.Model):
    non_proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    wiki_page = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.non_proprietary_name

class ProprietaryName(models.Model):
    proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
    non_proprietary_name = models.ForeignKey(Mediwiki)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.proprietary_name
```

So, it works! But I'm not so sure why.. Is this the best way to do it? Also, what about the Categories? Should they be change to foreign keys aswell?

```
>>> Mediwiki.objects.get(proprietaryname__proprietary_name="Aspirin")
<Mediwiki: acetylsalicylic acid>
>>>

>>> ProprietaryName.objects.get(proprietary_name="Aspirin").non_proprietary_name
<Mediwiki: acetylsalicylic acid> # Works also, what's preferable? 

>>>ProprietaryName.objects.filter(non_proprietary_name__non_proprietary_name="acetylsalicylic acid")
        [<ProprietaryName: Aspirin>, <ProprietaryName: ASS>]
        >>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many proprietary names, but no identical proprietary name can be assigned to more than one non-proprietary (generic) drug, so you need to change your relation from Many-To-Many to One-To-Many (nb. use CamelCase in class names, not underscores):

```
class Mediwiki(models.Model):
    non_proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True) # actual name
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    wiki_page = models.TextField()

class ProprietaryName(models.Model):
    proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True) #nick name
    non_proprietary_name = models.ForeignKey(Mediawiki)
```

then you can get all proprietary drugs for a non-proprietary name using `Mediawiki`'s `proprietaryname_set` property, and `ProprietaryName`'s `mediawiki` property for the other lookup. More on that in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/).

Comment: Again, thanks for your reply! Edited the original question, is that what you had in mind? Also, what about the Categories? Should the be changed to foreign keys aswell?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea, as for `category` - it should stay ManyToMany as a drug can fall into many categories and a category will contain many drugs.

Answer (score 1):

First your model name `Mediwiki` is not straightforward because each entry is just recording all information about a `Drug`. So just change that to `Drug` would make more sense.

In your current design, you are using m2m fields, which indicates that one `proprietary_name` could be used on multiple drugs. If you want all `Drug` non_proprietary_names return when you enter `proprietary_name`, just do:

```
Drug.objects.filter(proprietary_name__proprietary_name='Aspirin') \
            .values_list('non_proprietary_name', flat=True).distinct()
```

Check django doc about [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

If however, one `proprietary_name` can only describe one drug, you should make `Drug` as foreign key on model `Proprietary_name` to indicate one-to-many relationship:

```
class Proprietary_name(models.Model):
    proprietary_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    drug = models.ForeignKey(Drug)
```